# Como otimizar/simplificar CSS

Tags: css

Criei um álbum de fotos usando uma lista e customizando com CSS, mas ao meu ver o CSS ficou enorme, acho que não to sabendo como fazer meu código mais funcional, alguém pode me dar dicas?

```
@charset "utf-8";

ul#album-fotos {
    width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style: none;
}

ul#album-fotos li {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 5px solid #dddddd;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

ul#album-fotos li:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}

/*foto 01*/
ul#album-fotos li#foto01 {
    background: url('../imagens/galeria-01.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: 400px 400px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
ul#album-fotos li#foto01:hover {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-size: 200px 200px;
}
/*foto 02*/
ul#album-fotos li#foto02 {
    background: url('../imagens/galeria-02.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: 400px 400px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
ul#album-fotos li#foto02:hover {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-size: 200px 200px;
}
/*foto 03*/
ul#album-fotos li#foto03 {
    background: url('../imagens/galeria-03.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: 400px 400px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
ul#album-fotos li#foto03:hover {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-size: 200px 200px;
}
/*foto 04*/
ul#album-fotos li#foto04 {
    background: url('../imagens/galeria-04.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: 400px 400px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
ul#album-fotos li#foto04:hover {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-size: 200px 200px;
}
/*foto 05*/
ul#album-fotos li#foto05 {
    background: url('../imagens/galeria-05.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: 400px 400px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
ul#album-fotos li#foto05:hover {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-size: 200px 200px;
}
/*foto 06*/
ul#album-fotos li#foto06 {
    background: url('../imagens/galeria-06.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: 400px 400px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
ul#album-fotos li#foto06:hover {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-size: 200px 200px;
}

ul#album-fotos li span {
    opacity: 0;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    font-size: 11pt;
    line-height: 370px;
    padding: 5px; 

}
ul#album-fotos li:hover span {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Nem ta tão grande assim, rsrs, mas existem formas de organizar melhor isso sim, criando variáveis para propriedades que você vai usar varias vezes com o mesmo valor, ou caso no futuro você faça sites maiores, uma dica é separar o CSS de cada página em arquivos diferentes em vez de deixar tudo no mesmo arquivo CSS

Comment: https://codepen.io/valdeir2000/pen/qgoovQ?editors=1101

Comment: @ValdeirPsr gostei da abordagem pro nome da classe! Vc se incomoda seu eu incluir na minha resposta, não tinha me atentado nessa opção :D

Comment: @hugocsl Pode incluir. 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existem algumas formas para vc organizar melhor isso ai sim, vc pode criar variáveis para valores que se repetem muito, e agrupar classes que tenham as mesmas propriedades.

Como por exemplo vc repete as mesmas propriedades para todas as imagens e só muda o background, então uma das formas de organizar isso seria assim. Repare que no `:root` eu criei uma variável com o --tamanho `200px` isso pode facilitar caso vc quera mudar esse tamanho em todas as imagens de uma vez, e eu tb agrupei as classes que tinham os mesmo atributos.

Sobre o seletor que vc usou para as imagens, uma forma mais simplificada de fazer é como o [@ValdeirPsr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/99718/valdeir-psr) mencionou nos comentários que seria referenciar o elemento pelo atributo `id`.

Desse forma vc pode pegar todos os elementos que tenho o id começando com a palavra "foto" e transforma em um seletor único!

Logo todos esses seletores seriam simplificado para um seletor apenas

```
ul#album-fotos li#foto01,
ul#album-fotos li#foto02,
ul#album-fotos li#foto03,
ul#album-fotos li#foto04,
ul#album-fotos li#foto05,
ul#album-fotos li#foto06,
```

É o mesmo que apenas isso!

```
[id^="foto"]
```

**OBS:** No modelo abaixo fiz esse tratamento apenas no `:hover` para te ajudar a entender. Aqui tem mais detalhes de como fazer seleção por atributo no CSS: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Seletor_de_atributos

Vc tb declarou o seu background de maneira "extensa" separado cada uma das propriedades, mas com um *shorthand* vc coloca tudo em uma linha só. E valores iguais não precisam ser repetidos, por exemplo `background-position: 50% 50%;` pode ser só `background-position: 50%;` *(mas se vc quiser por uma questão de cross-browser pode manter os 2 valores, isso é praticamente irrelevante)*

```
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-size: 400px 400px;
background-color: #ffffff;
```

Seria o mesmo que isso no *shorthand*

```
background: 50%/400px #ffffff;
```

Segue uma proposta de reformatação.

```
@charset "utf-8";

:root {
    --tamanho: 200px;
    --tamanhox: 400px;
}
/* imagens */

ul#album-fotos li#foto01,
ul#album-fotos li#foto02,
ul#album-fotos li#foto03,
ul#album-fotos li#foto04,
ul#album-fotos li#foto05,
ul#album-fotos li#foto06, {
    background: 50%/var(--tamanhox) #ffffff;
}

/* aqui eu fiz uma seleção por atributo para pegar todos os IDs */
[id^="foto"]:hover {
    background: 0px/var(--tamanho);
}

ul#album-fotos {
    width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style: none;
}

ul#album-fotos li {
    float: left;
    width: var(--tamanho);
    height: var(--tamanho);
    margin: 10px;
    border: 5px solid #dddddd;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

ul#album-fotos li:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}

/*foto 01*/
ul#album-fotos li#foto01 {
    background: url('../imagens/galeria-01.jpg') no-repeat;
}
/*foto 02*/
ul#album-fotos li#foto02 {
    background: url('../imagens/galeria-02.jpg') no-repeat;
}
/*foto 03*/
ul#album-fotos li#foto03 {
    background: url('../imagens/galeria-03.jpg') no-repeat;
}
/*foto 04*/
ul#album-fotos li#foto04 {
    background: url('../imagens/galeria-04.jpg') no-repeat;
}
/*foto 05*/
ul#album-fotos li#foto05 {
    background: url('../imagens/galeria-05.jpg') no-repeat;
}
/*foto 06*/
ul#album-fotos li#foto06 {
    background: url('../imagens/galeria-06.jpg') no-repeat;
}

ul#album-fotos li span {
    opacity: 0;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    font-size: 11pt;
    line-height: 370px;
    padding: 5px; 

}
ul#album-fotos li:hover span {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Digamos que possua na página outro elemento com o id `#fotosGaleria`, ou `#fotoPrincipal`, ou `#fotosMenu`... a regra `[id^="foto"]:hover` vai lascar tudo :D... tinha que especificar apontando para as li's dentro de  #album-fotos... ficaria `#album-fotos [id^="foto"]:hover`... mas ainda acho melhor `#album-fotos li:hover`... pela lógica, esses id's #foto01, #foto02 etc.. só está servindo mesmo para diferenciar as imagens de fundo da cada uma.

Comment: Na verdade, nem precisaria de id's, bastava usar nth-child... O uso exagerado de id's é próprio de quem está começando a escrever códigos :), no caso o AP

Comment: @Sam realmente são muitos detalhes, e cada caso uma opção pode funcionar melhor, a ideia era passar mais os conceitos gerais. O nth-child tmj pode dar problema se ele.incluir um outro elemento entre uma.foto e outra etc, a verdade meus eh que colocar classe em id já não seria uma boa pratica, pelo menos no meu ponto de vista... []'s

Comment: Me ajudaram muito, valeu mesmo!

Comment: @FilipePetter que bom que te ajudou. Sempre tenha em mente os conceitos que abordamos nas respostas aqui, eles são fundamentais para trabalhar bem e de forma prática com CSS. Sucesso! Abs

Answer (score 5):

Além de agrupar propriedades comuns, você pode eliminar coisas desnecessárias, como por exemplo:

```
ul#album-fotos li#foto05 { ... }
```

Se um `id` é único numa página, você pode ir direto ao id `#foto05`, sem precisar escrever o caminho enorme até ele, já economizando muito código e tornando até mais fácil a leitura, ficando assim:

```
#foto05{ ... }
```

Desta forma, agrupando todos os elementos com propriedades comuns numa mesma regra, ficaria assim:

```
#foto01, #foto02, #foto03,
#foto04, #foto05, #foto06 {
   background-position: 50% 50%;
   background-size: 400px 400px;
   background-color: #fff;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

A parte do `:hover`, também não faz sentido:

```
ul#album-fotos li#foto01:hover { ... }
ul#album-fotos li#foto02:hover { ... }
etc..
```

Ora, se todas as `li` dentro de `#album-fotos` sofrem o mesmo efeito no `:hover`, não faz sentido separar usando id's diferentes. Bastaria uma regra apenas:

```
#album-fotos li:hover{ ... }
```

Isso também serve para outras regras do seu CSS, ficando no geral assim:

```
#album-fotos {
    width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style: none;
}

#album-fotos li {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 5px solid #dddddd;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

#album-fotos li:hover {
   background-position: 0 0;
   background-size: 200px 200px;
   transform: scale(1.5);
}

#foto01, #foto02, #foto03,
#foto04, #foto05, #foto06 {
   background-position: 50% 50%;
   background-size: 400px 400px;
   background-color: #fff;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#foto01 {
   background-image: url('../imagens/galeria-01.jpg');
}

#foto02 {
   background-image: url('../imagens/galeria-02.jpg');
}

#foto03 {
   background-image: url('../imagens/galeria-03.jpg');
}

#foto04 {
   background-image: url('../imagens/galeria-04.jpg');
}

#foto05 {
   background-image: url('../imagens/galeria-05.jpg');
}

#foto06 {
   background-image: url('../imagens/galeria-06.jpg');
}

#album-fotos li span {
   opacity: 0;
   color: white;
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
   font-size: 11pt;
   line-height: 370px;
   padding: 5px; 
}

#album-fotos li:hover span {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

Se todas as `<li>` em `#album-fotos` forem as que possuem id's de `01` a `06`, nem precisaria disso:

```
#foto01, #foto02, #foto03,
#foto04, #foto05, #foto06 {
   background-position: 50% 50%;
   background-size: 400px 400px;
   background-color: #fff;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Bastaria incluir as propriedades acima dentro do estilo abaixo:

```
#album-fotos li {
   float: left;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   margin: 10px;
   border: 5px solid #dddddd;
   background-color: white;
   box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
   transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
   background-position: 50% 50%;
   background-size: 400px 400px;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

> Ficando assim agora:

```
#album-fotos {
    width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style: none;
}

#album-fotos li {
   float: left;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   margin: 10px;
   border: 5px solid #dddddd;
   background-color: white;
   box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
   transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
   background-position: 50% 50%;
   background-size: 400px 400px;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#album-fotos li:hover {
   background-position: 0 0;
   background-size: 200px 200px;
   transform: scale(1.5);
}

#foto01 {
   background-image: url('../imagens/galeria-01.jpg');
}

#foto02 {
   background-image: url('../imagens/galeria-02.jpg');
}

#foto03 {
   background-image: url('../imagens/galeria-03.jpg');
}

#foto04 {
   background-image: url('../imagens/galeria-04.jpg');
}

#foto05 {
   background-image: url('../imagens/galeria-05.jpg');
}

#foto06 {
   background-image: url('../imagens/galeria-06.jpg');
}

#album-fotos li span {
   opacity: 0;
   color: white;
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
   font-size: 11pt;
   line-height: 370px;
   padding: 5px; 
}

#album-fotos li:hover span {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

**Vamos ver isso funcionando:**

```css
#album-fotos {
    width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style: none;
}

#album-fotos li {
   float: left;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   margin: 10px;
   border: 5px solid #dddddd;
   background-color: white;
   box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
   transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
   background-position: 50% 50%;
   background-size: 400px 400px;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#album-fotos li:hover {
   background-position: 0 0;
   background-size: 200px 200px;
   transform: scale(1.5);
}

#foto01 {
   background-image: url('https://http2.mlstatic.com/S_889901-MLB20440401736_102015-O.jpg');
}

#foto02 {
   background-image: url('https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/monica/images/0/0a/Festa_turma_da_monica_painel_decorativo_anjinho_piffer.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130930232726&path-prefix=pt-br');
}

#foto03 {
   background-image: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/57a4a607f5e231c1eb1226ce/57aa06ef37c581879046603f/5b29055d758d460f539bbe74/1529415060473/JAr0-BQG_400x400.jpg');
}

#foto04 {
   background-image: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/52557d46e4b0f3efcbd81dc8/t/5a395602085229099e52ea13/1527183612488/Final_HCD_Logo12072016_800X800.jpg');
}

#foto05 {
   background-image: url('https://d2sg07zx6lm3f.cloudfront.net/s3fs-public/styles/square_cropped/public/instagram/46667487_739600606423067_5494384775873874429_n.jpg%3F_nc_ht%3Dscontent.cdninstagram.com?CccicumQOzt7CnJq0uLz0qlQ4mwzPe5D&itok=dOHlNMfU');
}

#foto06 {
   background-image: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5009914ee4b0779c48ca1d4a/578d75726a49637d20b62305/578d7572725e257ad6877c3e/1468889029160/About+%283%29.jpg');
}

#album-fotos li span {
   opacity: 0;
   color: white;
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
   font-size: 11pt;
   line-height: 370px;
   padding: 5px; 
}

#album-fotos li:hover span {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul id="album-fotos">
   <li id="foto01">
      <span>foto 1</span>
   </li>
   <li id="foto02">
      <span>foto 2</span>
   </li>
   <li id="foto03">
      <span>foto 3</span>
   </li>
   <li id="foto04">
      <span>foto 4</span>
   </li>
   <li id="foto05">
      <span>foto 5</span>
   </li>
   <li id="foto06">
      <span>foto 6</span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Excelente explicação, obrigado!